# Django Rest Framework doesn't serialize SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models:

```
from django.db import models

STATUSES = (
    ('f', 'Finished'),
)


class Battery(models.Model):
    energy = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    current = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Charger(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUSES)
```

And I want to create serializer that will serialize this 2 models together. My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Battery, Charger


class BatterySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Battery


class ChargerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Charger

    def get_status(self, obj):
        return obj.get_status_display()


class DeviceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    battery = BatterySerializer()
    charger = ChargerSerializer()
    some_field = serializers.CharField()
```

Because Charger model has choices in status field I add SerializerMethodField for displaying full status. Then I create a view like this:

```
class DeviceView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        battery = Battery.objects.get(id=1)
        charger = Charger.objects.get(id=1)
        battery_serializer = BatterySerializer(battery)
        charger_serializer = ChargerSerializer(charger)
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(data={
            'battery': battery_serializer.data,
            'charger': charger_serializer.data,
            'some_field': 'some_text'
        })
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.validated_data)
        else:
            return Response(status = 500)
```

But when I call this view it returns json with empty charger field:

```
{
    "battery": {
        "energy": "12",
        "current": "34"
    },
    "charger": {},
    "some_field": "some_text"
}
```

But when I create a view that serialize only Charger model:

```
class ChargerView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        charger = Charger.objects.get(id=1)
        charger_serializer = ChargerSerializer(charger)
        return Response(charger_serializer.data)
```

It works and it returns this json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "Finished"
}
```

Why this happens? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: why can't you call both  `BatterySerializer` and `ChargerSerializer`  methods independently in your view and return them? Since that is what your `DeviceSerializer`is doing.

Comment: How I can return them together?

Comment: like this `{
            'battery': battery.__dict__,
            'charger': charger.__dict__,
            'some_field': 'some_text'
        }` ? not sure if this is the right way though.

Comment: What are you validating in `serializer.is_valid()`? Can you directly return `Response(serializer.data)` and see what you get?

Comment: When I try to return `Response(serializer.data)` It raise AssertionError: `When a serializer is passed a data keyword argument you must call .is_valid() before attempting to access the serialized .data representation.
You should either call .is_valid() first, or access .initial_data instead.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of `Serializers`:

1. `instance` is passed when you have an object and you have to serialize it. [(link)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects)
2. `data` is passed when you already have serialized data and you want to deserialize it and create an instance out of it.[(link)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects)
3. both `instance` and `data` is passed when you have an instance and you want to update it.[(link)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

Looking at your case, I don't think you need option 2 and 3 because you have the `battery` and `charger` instances and you need to serialize it together. You are not creating a new instance and you also don't have to validate it so passing it as `data` is not required.

There are two ways you could do this:

1.Create a class `Device` so you could create an instance of it and then serialize it using `DeviceSerializer`:

```
class Device(object):

    def __init__(self, battery, charger, some_field):
        self.battery = battery
        self.charger = charger
        self.some_field  = some_field

class DeviceView(APIView):
    # then in the DeviceView you could create an instance and pass to the serializer
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        battery = Battery.objects.get(id=1)
        charger = Charger.objects.get(id=1)
        device = Device(battery=battery, charger=charger, some_field='some_text')
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(instance=device)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

2.If you don't want to go with creating a new class you could directly create a `dict` and pass it as instance:

```
class DeviceView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        battery = Battery.objects.get(id=1)
        charger = Charger.objects.get(id=1)
        # create a dict with required objects and pass it as instance of serializer
        device = {'battery': battery, 'charger': charger, 'some_field': 'some_text'}
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(instance=device)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're doing work you don't have to. If you serialize the charger before passing it to the `DeviceSerializer`, you're actually passing a `dict`, not a `Charger` instance, and the `dict` has no `get_status_display` method.  You should pass the `Battery` and `Charger` directly like so:

```
class DeviceView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        battery = Battery.objects.get(id=1)
        charger = Charger.objects.get(id=1)
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(instance={
            'battery': battery,
            'charger': charger,
            'some_field': 'some_text',
        })
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note that you can also simplify by replacing the SerializerMethodField with a CharField:

```
class ChargerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.CharField(source='get_status_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Charger
```

Edit: As AKS pointed out, a serializer should be passed `instance` rather than `data` when serializing (`data` is for deserializing), and you don't need to check `.is_valid()`

Comment: It's doesn't work. `Invalid data, expected a dictionary, but got Battery/Charger`

Comment: Edited to pass dict as `instance` instead of `data`

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the keyword data when creating the serializer instance, witch is only used when deserializing data.
you should create the DeviceSerializer with an object with the fields you want.
I haven't tested, but maybe something like this

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, battery, charger, name, ):
        self.battery = battery
        self.charger = charger
        self.some_field = name

class DeviceView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        d=Device(Battery.objects.get(id=1),Charger.objects.get(id=1),"somename")
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(d)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```